How to test Spark 4.0 preview on Databricks Community edition
Question: How can we install (use) Preview Release of Spark 4.0 in Databricks Community Edition? I'm using Windows 10. When creating a cluster, the highest version it shows in the dropdown is 15.4 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.5.0, Scala 2.12)
Remarks:
If preview release is not available in Databricks, where can I test it? The above linked page from Databricks team states: Preview release is meant to give the community early access to try the code that will become Spark 4.0. If you would like to test the release, please download it, and send feedback using either the mailing lists or JIRA.

Per the cluster version you can select it has it's own Spark version - you cannot test Spark 4 on any existing Databricks Runtime (DBR) as of 3rd September 24 (15.4 is the highest with no public 16 beta).
You can only run the version of spark offered by the DBR and cannot supply your own.  DBRs do not run OSS spark, but a custom optimised version, you cannot upgrade it or swap it out even if you ran Scala instead of python.

Where can we test this preview release? I just added a Remarks section to my post above.

the answer is the same.  Unless Databricks provides a runtime using a given Spark version you cannot test it on Databricks.
